# ManageIQ / Cloudforms dynamic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redhat, manageiq

I am trying to create a form to manage users permissions in my tool.
[Here is my static form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8axK4.png)

When the user selects “Revoked” Membership, I want all the tools below to be disabled and to take the “None” value.
When the user selects “Administrator” Membership, I want all the tools below to be disabled and to take the “Administrator” value.

How can I achieve that with ruby script in ManageIQ/Cloudforms?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add some code to your question. People will help you with your code but not write the code for you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want dynamic forms.  You can read more about them here - https://pemcg.gitbooks.io/introduction-to-cloudforms-automation/content/chapter17/service_dialogs.html

In your case it sounds like you would make your membership field trigger a re-evaluation of the other dynamic fields, which causes automate to recalculate both the values and the visibility.